# Java field access versus getter syntax

Tags: java, class, field, getter, accessor

If have the following class ...

```
/**
 * Two dimensional cartesian point.
 */
public class Point {
  public final double x;
  private final double y;

  public double y(){
  return this.y;
  }

}
```

I can retrieve values as follows Point.x  or Point.y()
I thought it was good practice in OO languages to encapsulate data by not making it directly accessible and instead using accessors, but it would seem that using directly field access is more normal and readable.

Why doesn't Java allow me to dispense which the ()'s for function calls that take no parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you think about it, code would become completely unreadable. When you encountered something like `foo.bar`, yhou wouldn't know whether it was accessing a field, or calling a method.

It could only work if you introduced a third kind of construct besides fields and methods: properties. If Java supported properties, accessing them without `()` would not harm readability. There's no technical reason for why there are no property-like constructs in Java, it was just a design decision.

But allowing the omission of parentheses in any method call without a parameter is a bad idea.

Comment: Did you look into Scala? It allows dropping empty parens. Whether that makes it unreadable is an open question, though :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, that was my point really. It is technically possible (and is indeed done in Scala) but it doesn't look pretty.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't thought about the potential confusion caused by dropping parentheses. But I thought that Java was big into enforcing OO principles. However, when you look at the builtin classes, you are never calling a function to retrieve a value. That's why I'm wondering about a different usage pattern in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't let you do that due to a language design choice made around 1995. Java's goal was to be a "blue collar language", which means that there should be a low total number of constructs and each construct should be as obvious as possible.

BTW instead of asking yourself "Why Java doesn't let me drop the parens", why not ask yourself "Why does Java make me write all those redundant getters and setters?" Most other languages to that automatically.

The point of getters/setters is not so much encapsulation (of which there is effectively none if you just transparently get/set values), but dynamic dispatch. Accessors, as any other method, may be overridden; also some frameworks insist on using them instead of direct field access.

For me, the choice to have `public final double` fields is just fine. Look at `GridBagConstraints` for an example of public fields in a JSE class.